# Copy file to disk image (*.img)/analogue to mcopy on Mac

Tags: linux, macos

I want to copy few files to image of disk (*.img extension). On linux this command is used:

`mcopy -i "$target_img" $file ::/`

What is same command for mac (OS X)? How can I copy files to image?

Answer (score 1):

Apparently my last answer doesn't fit the criteria of the moderator...  well heres an answer acceptable in their "format." i guess i wont get back the little reputation i received that the admin stripped me from. its tough being 20 yr old silicon valley techy ;)

- The hdiutil command can also be used to create a disk image based upon a folder.

  ```
  hdiutil create {imagename}.dmg -volname "{Name of volume}" -srcfolder /{path to folder}'
  ```
- Using the above command, we could perform the following:

  ```
  hdiutil create ~/Desktop/newimage.dmg -volname "New Disk Image" -srcfolder ~/Desktop/myfolder
  ```
- The name of the disk image and volume name are two different things, the first simply refers to the filename of the disk image created. When the image is mounted or restored to a disk, the volume name is what's referred to. So if I mount this new disk image, you'll see OS X mounts it as "New Disk Image".
- Disk images generated using the above methods are read-only and formatted as HFS+ by default, though their size will be just enough to contain all the data needed.

Standard disk images cannot increase in size, so you'll need to specify a particular size if you intend to be adding data to it later. The parameter -size can be used to specify the size of the disk image to create.

If you need will need to modify or add more data to the disk image, use the parameter -format UDRW which represents read/write.

Combining all of the above, the command would be:

```
 hdiutil create ~/Desktop/newimage.dmg -volname "New Disk Image" -size 1g -format UDRW -srcfolder ~/Desktop/myfolder
```

Comment: How to create img file? That commands creates dmg file (even if I set extension as *.img). It adds dmg at the end.

Comment: That did not work for floppy. Right solution: create it, mount it, write files and unmount. That works.

Comment: both .dmg and .img are image files. did you literally try changing the file extension by clicking it and changing the text? 

please read up on your file extensions.
[DMG](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/.dmg)
[IMG](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/.img)

an .img is normally an "image" (=copy) of a disk (as dvd or cd), done e.g. with iDVD; the .dmg (which translates as "disk image"...) is in many cases not the virtual copy of a whole disk, but in many cases contains a folder with lots of stuff (to install, for instance)